# How can we create a simple JSP web based application without the use of spring frame work , using gradle build tool only?

Tags: java, gradle

As  I am currently using eclipse IDE, can i create the aforesaid application with the use of gradle build tool only? If so, please elaborate the steps in creating the application. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try following the instructions at

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

Where it tells how to package a framework-less java web application with Gradle.